# Do I need to use the same URI returned from my insert() method to fetch a row

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a simple doubt regarding Android Content providers .

While inserting a single record into db I am returning a URI by appending the _id fetched from the `insert()` method and also I am calling `getContentResolver().notifyChange()` on this URI .

So now my URI will be `"content://CONTENT_AUTHORITY/TABLE_NAME/_id"`.

But while fetching a single record , I am fetching it by selecting another id (a composite key) let it be `movie_id` .

So to fetch this my uri will be `"content://CONTENT_AUTHORITY/TABLE_NAME/movie_id"`

Now i will be able to fetch a record since my URI matcher matches only /TABLE_NAME/# records.

But what happens to the first URI which was created, on which I had created the `notifyChange()` method?

Is it bad practice to do so, since I am using `notifyChange(`) on one URI but I am fetching using other URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is indeed that the uri you return in the `insert()` method can be used to query the exact same object. Obvisouly it is easier if you only have one uri format, and some workflow might be extremely usefull.

But then again, there's no issue with having alias uris too, and be able to query a row from a table based on different unique ids. But if you do that, please use a different URI, so that your content provider knows which query to perform.

In your example, I'd let the `content://CONTENT_AUTHORITY/TABLE_NAME/_id` query entries by the row id, and add a `content://CONTENT_AUTHORITY/TABLE_NAME/MOVIE/movie_id` uri to query entries by composite key